# The .NET NuGet Package `Magento.NetCore` Has No Sample Code - How to use it?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, c#

I want to use C# to call against the Magento 2 REST API. The NuGet package [`Magento.NetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magento.NetCore/) seems like it might be a fairly complete C# library, but there is no sample code. Even just to create a connection.

Can anyone post some code to show you this library works?